Sum of infinite complex exponentials
I asked this question in the math site but haven't got an answer yet, thought I would try here.
I've been revising a few lectures here: https://youtu.be/WgaNe3euf4s?t=9m6s and at the time stamped point in the link, the professor asks to prove an interesting result.
Specifically,
\begin{align}
&A_{0}\cos(\Omega_0t+\phi_0)\\
+&A_{0}\cos((2\pi/T\pm \Omega_0)t\pm\phi_0)\\
+&A_{0}\cos((2\times2\pi/T\pm \Omega_0)t\pm\phi_0)\\
&\ldots &= 0
\end{align}
when $t \ne nT$ for integer n.
For $t = nT$, the sum does diverge and seems easy to prove, but for the non-sampled points, I can't seem to show it. I've tried applying trig identities on the individual terms and I managed to get something like
$1+2A_{0}\cos(2\pi/T)t+2A_{0}\cos(2\times2\pi/T)t+\dots$
but I don't know how to proceed. I feel like I need to bring in complex exponentials and find some geometric series. But not sure.

Try to write your equation in summation notation. From there, it should be pretty straightforward to get to the answer provided.

$$ \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t-n) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{j 2 \pi k t} $$
